# Detail fragment over listing fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments - Listing and detail. Initially I load the listing fragment in the container of the activity using

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, listingFrag);
ft.commit();
```

On tapping an item in the listing fragment I load the detail fragment using

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.content_frame, detailFrag);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

On loading detail fragment I do not get the onPause call of the listing fragment. Neither do I get the onResume call of the listing fragment on coming back from detail fragment (using the system back button).

Also, when I am in the detail fragment, putting the app to background calls the onPause of both the listing and detail fragments. On getting back the app from background, onResume of both listing and detail screens get called.

The above mentioned behaviors are quite unexpected. 
I would want
1) listing fragment's onResume to be called on coming back from listing screen
2) listing fragment's onPause to be called on loading detail fragment
3) only detail fragment's onPause to be called when the app is put to background
4) only detail fragment's onResume to be called when the app is brought back from background

Can some one please explain a way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onPause` and `onResume` in fragment are just the reflection of `onPause` and `onResume` in  `Activity`.

So every time you go from one activity to another all the fragments of the first activity will call `onPause` and all the fragments of the 2nd activity will call `onResume`.

This functions are not for fragment visible/add or remove.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! Do you know of some other way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

When you display the detailed fragment, you add it which means that both the listing and the detailed fragments are active at the same time. Hence both of them receive `onPause()` and `onResume()`.

You should instead try replacing the listing fragment with the details fragment. That will cause `onPause()` in the listing fragment and only one fragment will be active at a time.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, listingFrag);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();

FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, detailFrag);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: I did think of this option too. But this is not going to help me since I am downloading the contents of listing screen in its onCreateView. So if the listing fragment is replaced when I go back from detail, it would be re-downloading all the contents.